# What is the action of maxwellian electromagnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, action

What is the Lagrangian formulation of classical electromagnetism? Specifically I want to know the action in classical electromagnetism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lagrangian of electromagnetism is
$$\mathcal{L}=-\tfrac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}$$
We then plug in the definition $F_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu$. Using the standard definitions of the $E$ and $B$ fields, this leads to
$$\mathcal{L}=\tfrac{1}{2}(E^2-B^2)$$
See [this Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian#Electromagnetism_in_special_relativity) for more details. Since classical E&M is relativistic, your request is entirely equivalent to "What is the Lagrangian of E&M in SR?"